# SharePoint JS Button Ribbon is not reading functions

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, ribbon, button

So i have created a new button called "Closed" using SPD 2013, and using "**Communaction site**", inside this site i have a list of type **Default experience**. The button location is **"View Ribbon"** and i manage a workflow to this button to update the status column to closed.

The problem is when i select more then 1 item, the button disappear from the ribbon so i can only select 1 item, so how can i enable the multiple selection for this button ?

[image: Button Action]

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code below to a text file and rename it myScript.html and save it. Upload this file to SiteAssets library. Now go to list view page and click edit page. Add a web part called "Content Editor Web Part". Now put the link to the file in the link property in edit web part. Now perform your actions. It worked as expected for me.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("AddCustomUserActionToRibbon");

function AddCustomUserActionToRibbon(){
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(AddCustomUserAction, "sp.js"); 
} 
var oListItem;  
function AddCustomUserAction() {  
    //Get the client context and list object  
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Clients");  
    list.get_userCustomActions().clear();
    //Get the custom user action collection and add the user action  
    var customUserAction = list.get_userCustomActions().add();  
    //Set the location of the user action  
    customUserAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView');  
    //Add the properties for the custom action  
    var userActionExtension = '<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">' + '<CommandUIDefinitions>' + '<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">' + '<Button Id="DannyJessee.MarkItemsFinishedButton" ' + 'Command="cmdMarkItemsFinished" ' + 'Sequence="0" ' + 'Image16by16="/_layouts/images/kpinormallarge-0.gif" ' + 'Image32by32="/_layouts/images/kpinormallarge-0.gif" ' + 'Description="Mark as Finished" ' + 'LabelText="Mark as Finished" ' + 'TemplateAlias="o2"/>' + '</CommandUIDefinition>' + '</CommandUIDefinitions>' + '<CommandUIHandlers>' + '<CommandUIHandler Command="cmdMarkItemsFinished" ' + 'CommandAction="javascript:MarkItemsFinished();" EnabledScript="javascript:EnableFinishedButton();" />' + '</CommandUIHandlers>' + '</CommandUIExtension>';  
    //Add the command UI extension and update the custom user action  
    customUserAction.set_commandUIExtension(userActionExtension)  
    customUserAction.update();  
    //Load the client context and execute the batch  
    context.load(list, 'UserCustomActions');  
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {  
        console.log("Custom User Action added successfully to ribbon.");  
    }, function(sender, args) {  
        console.log(args.get_message());  
    });  
}

function EnableFinishedButton() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list;
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var totalSelectedItems = selectedItems.length;

    if (totalSelectedItems > 0) {
        var web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);

        // We will use this variable to determine whether EnableFinishedButton() is being called directly or by RefreshCommandUI()
        var hadToMakeCall = false;

        if (typeof this.itemRows == "undefined" || this.itemRows.length != totalSelectedItems) {
            // This will be true if this is the first time an item has been selected in the list OR if the selected items have changed, forcing the need to check again
            hadToMakeCall = true;
            GetItemsStatus();
        }

        // If we just issued the async call, do not enable the button yet
        if (hadToMakeCall) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            // Once the call has returned, set the enabled status based on the returned value
            return this._can_be_enabled;
        }
    }
    else {
        this.itemRows = undefined;
        return false;
    }
    function GetItemsStatus() {
        // Store the selected list items in an array where their values can be checked
        itemRows = [];

        for (i in selectedItems) {
            itemRows[i] = list.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            context.load(itemRows[i]);
        }

        context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onGetItemsSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onGetItemsQueryFailed));
    }

    function onGetItemsSuccess() {
        this._can_be_enabled = true;

        // Iterate through all selected items. If one is false, the value of _can_be_enabled will be false and the button will not be enabled
        for (i in itemRows) {
            //this._can_be_enabled = this._can_be_enabled && itemRows[i].get_item("Status") == "In Progress";

            if((this._can_be_enabled && itemRows[i].get_item("Status") == "Pending") || (this._can_be_enabled && itemRows[i].get_item("Status") == "Approved")){
                this._can_be_enabled = true; 
            }
            else{
                this._can_be_enabled = false;
            }
        }

        // Now we can call the EnabledScript function again
        RefreshCommandUI();
    }

    function onGetItemsQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
}
function MarkItemsFinished() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
    var i;
    for (i in selectedItems) {
        // Update the "Status" field of each selected item to have a value of "Finished"
        var listItem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
        listItem.set_item("Status", "Finished");
        listItem.update();
    }
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onUpdateItemsSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, onUpdateItemsFailed));

    function onUpdateItemsSuccess() {
        alert("Items updated!");
    }

    function onUpdateItemsFailed(sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
}   
</script>
```

Check the screenshot below. the button will be activated only if status column has a value "In Progress"
[image]

As far as I know, running workflows using custom actions is possile for 1 item only. You can check [this](https://www.abelsolutions.com/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/) article and try adding the script.

Comment: Doesn't work i replace it with var totalSelectedItems = selectedItems.length;
In my console i get 2 errors:
VM176:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: EnableFinishedButton is not defined
and MarkItemsFinished is not defined
@harshal gite

Comment: Put a breakpoint in browser debugger on the line selectedItems.length and when debugger arrives there, just write selectedItems in console and check take a scteenshot of that result and add it here please

Comment: Its not a file to find it in a source to put a breakpoint because i add it by adding a web part then inside script editor i paste my code. Anyway this is my sources files: https://i.imgur.com/K970BlI.png @harshal gite

Comment: I followed your steps and i copy your code but i got same errors in the console and the button still not clickable.
My main goal of this code is to make multiple selection for many items and once they click on Mark as finished i want to update the status column to finished. Can i do this on SharePoint designer ? If yes how could i do that and skip the coding part. @harshal gite

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't works for me and yes i know it will be clickable if i choose the items that contains "In Progress" take a look my errors:
https://i.imgur.com/3Y4qhLd.png @harshal gite

Comment: where have you added the code?

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake i added the code in another page, now it works man ! I am really sorry i didn't knew that i have to add it in list page. One more question how can i make the button disabled because whenever you click on the button it will add a new button to the ribbon. @harshal gite

Comment: use the edited code now and please up vote if your complete requirement is fulfilled.

Comment: I am trying to add another status check in the code so i want the button to be clickable when the status is equal to pending & approved i try to edit this line:
        for (i in itemRows) {
            this._can_be_enabled = this._can_be_enabled && itemRows[i].get_item("Status") == "Pending";
   this._can_be_enabled = this._can_be_enabled && itemRows[i].get_item("Status") == "Approved";
        }
But it didn't work any idea why ? @harshal gite

Comment: Try the updated code

Comment: Yes now it's selectable but the problem is if i select a line with status equal to Closed or Rejected the button still clickable i want to make it disabled when its equal to Closed and rejected, Thanks for help @harshal gite

Comment: Put else below it and make it false

Comment: It works now thank you very much ! @harshal gite

Comment: Is it possible to add the same code in my Communaction Site using Modern Experience not the classic one @harshal gite

Comment: You dont have a top ribbon in modern SharePoint

Comment: yes but i just created the button on SPD 2013,but i can't select more than 1 item its not possible to add the same code ?

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: Umm, you have any idea how can i make it visible when selecting multiple items because if i select 2 items the button disappear. Here when i select 1 item https://i.imgur.com/NpZgJaI.png

Comment: Can you update the question with the code?

Comment: Yes sure one moment i will edit my post what i mean

Comment: I have updated my question. I am not using code i just created a workflow to achieve it but i wanna know how can i enable multiple selection for this button. @harshal gite

Comment: Check the updated answer. and please do not add more comments. You can always post a new question.

Comment: I will post a new question about this and check the tutorial you send it to me. Thank you @harshal gite